# Проверить принадлежность точки заштрихованной области

Tags: геометрия, lisp, autocad

Здравствуйте, снова я. Задача в общем такая: нужно считать с файла точки и проверить, находится ли каждая точка в заштрихованной области. Реализовать в AutoLISP.

Так вот, написать на AutoLISP не проблема, сам сделаю. Но вот я не знаю, как можно проверить принадлежность точки к фигуре. Может, есть в Autocad функция проверки точки или где-то описывается способ проверки?

Данные такие:

Длинна стороны квазрата: 4.

Диаметр окружности: 2.

Координаты центра окружности: (0, 0).

[image: Схема]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея очень простая, нужно проверить, что точка принадлежит квадрату и при этом не принадлежит кругу.

С учётом того, что центр фигуры находится в начале координат, принадлежность точки (x, y) квадрату проверяется условием:

```
(-2 <= x <= 2) && (-2 <= y <= 2)
```

где `2` - половина стороны квадрата.

Принадлежность кругу проверяется следующим условием:

```
x^2 + y^2 <= 1
```

где `1` - радиус окружности.

То есть финальное условие будет:

```
(-2 <= x <= 2) && (-2 <= y <= 2) && (x^2 + y^2 >= 1)
```

Если границы окружности и квадрата не должны входить в разрешённую область, то неравенства должны выть строгими.

Comment: Спасибо большое, не думал, что это довольно просто. (думаю, надо как-то будет подтянуть свои знания геометрии)